# How to access Mysql Database running on windows localhost:3006 from Ubuntu VM

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, ubuntu, localhost

[image]

Im trying to access `MySQL Database` on windows from a `NodeJS` Application in ubuntu VM. I have enabled MySQL Remote Connections but still getting the error in image.

Comment: This is because `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` does not have mysql installed, your VM is, you have to enable mysql remote connection and use your VM ip address to connect instead of  `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I have updated my question after following your instructions.

Comment: are you using VBOX or VMWare? also can you check while the VM running if the port 3306 is accessible? and what is your MySQL port in my.cnf?